# DJANGO : How to filter the last data collected for each type of object in a model?

Tags: django, django-models, filter, django-queryset

Let's say I have this model

```
class TreeCensus(models.Model):

    name            = models.CharField() #Oak, elm, ...
    identified_at   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I want to get a QS with the last Census of each tree.

I tried naively this

```
TreeCensus.object.order_by('name').last()
```

But It obviously returned me the last of all the TreeCensus objects.

So what is the best way (or at least a good one) to do this?
For example if there are 2 Oak in the QS I want to get the first one filtered

Comment: `TreeCensus.objects.values('name').annotate(item=Max('identified_at')).order_by('name')` with `from django.db.models import Max`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [**`.annotate(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) with:

```
from django.db.models import Max

TreeCensus.objects.values('name').annotate(
    last_seen=Max('identified_at')
).order_by('name')
```

This will produce a `QuerySet` of dictionaries with `name` and `last_seen` as keys where `last_seen` will contain the largest (latest) timestamp for that `name`.